# How can I watch the content of Locator objects in the debugger?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, playwright

Consider the following code:

```
test("homepage has title and links to intro page", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://playwright.dev/");

  const links = page.getByRole("link");
  const count = await links.count();
  console.log("count is " + count);
});
```

I know from my count variable that there are 31 links on the page. But shouldn't I also be able to get this information in the debugger via the
*links* variable? How would I "browse" the *links* variable to see all links and their count?

There are many "properties" in the *links* variable on the left side, but I can't see how to find something useful there:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible because the `links` variable does not contain that data: the counts [are queried when you call `.count()`](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/main/packages/playwright-core/src/client/locator.ts#L201). The only way is to "browse" the links is to [evaluate the `await links.count()` expression in the debugger](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug#top-level-await) and view the result or step over the `links.count()` call and see the value of the `counts` variable.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want to access the DOM element, and read it's properties. If that's what you need you can use the [`locator.elementHandles()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-element-handles), which will return `Promise<Array<ElementHandle>>`

and you can then get an Element attribute

```
test("homepage has title and links to intro page", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://playwright.dev/");

  const links = page.getByRole("link");
  const count = await links.count();

  const handles = await links.elementHandles()

  const attributePromises = handles.map(handle => handle.getAttribute('href'));

  console.log(await Promise.all(attributePromises))
});
```